# How to differentiate between two identical href links with only PHP (or another way around this)

Tags: php, href, crud

I am making a CRUD application for school where I have a seperate postal code table in my database. This consists of just the 3 columns 'postcode', 'adres' & 'woonplaats'.

I am showing each postal code in a table with Update and Delete button next to it. When Update is pressed the row in the table changes to a form with the data pre filled. as shown below (it goed to the first part of the if statement):

```
if ($row['postcode'] == $_GET['postcode']) {
?>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST">
    <td><input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["postcode"]); ?>" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="straat" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["adres"]); ?>" required></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="woonplaats" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["woonplaats"]); ?>" required></td>
    <td><button type="submit" name="update_postcode">Save</button><a href="postcodes.php">Cancel</a></td>
    <td>----</td>
</form>
<?php
} else {   
    ?>           
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["postcode"]) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["adres"]) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["woonplaats"]) ?></td>
    <td><a href="postcodes.php?postcode=<?php echo $row['postcode']; ?>">Update</a></td>
    <td><a href="postcodes.php?postcode=<?php echo $row["postcode"]; ?>&adres=<?php $row["adres"]; ?>">Delete</a></td> 
    <?php            
}
```

The thing is: My teacher gave me feedback that I have to change. He stated that I don't need to add the adres as a parameter to the delete link. The reason I did this is so I can differentiate between which link is clicked. When I remove the adres parameter on the Delete link then I have 2 identical links and pressing both will result in it going to the first part of the if statement (the update part).

He also wants me to have 1 page (and php file) where I combine all the CRUD functions for this...

How can I differentiate between which link is pressed if they are both identical?
I can NOT use any other language other than PHP and HTML for this.

If I can't differentiate between these same links, what is a good alternative to do in this case?

Comment: Important actions that change or delete content, should not be triggered via GET requests to begin with - search engines or browser extensions might "follow" those links, and then deletion would happen, without the user having actually actively triggered it. The Delete button should ideally be part of the/a form with method="POST" itself, and submit the value of the record you want to delete.

Comment: And FYI, the way you placed your form there, is not allowed in HTML to begin with - you can not nest a form into a table in that position; either the form has to go around the _whole_ table, or it has to be contained within a single table cell.

Comment: @CBroe Ah okay. I didn't know that it should happen through POST only. So the best way for me now would be to remake this as a whole (also considering the form inside table part) and to use a POST form to delete (and update?) the rows?

Comment: @CBroe I can't set your comment as answer to this post now. Think it would be good for someone with same situations :)

Answer (score 0):

**Answered by CBroe. Thought this would be good to mark as anwer for beginner PHP programmers running into the same 'problem' (train of thought)**

Important actions that change or delete content, should not be triggered via GET requests to begin with - search engines or browser extensions might "follow" those links, and then deletion would happen, without the user having actually actively triggered it. The Delete button should ideally be part of the/a form with method="POST" itself, and submit the value of the record you want to delete. –